# How to get a response from the server after changing the selendroid server default port?

Tags: selendroid

I'm new to Selendroid and iv been trying to test an application by following standard instructions.

When the default port was 4444, test failed indicating that the server failed to respond. When I checked connection statuses, 4444 port had 'time-wait' and 8080 port had 'established' as corresponding statuses. So, I changed selendroid server port to 8080 to see if it solves the issue. Now when I run the test no command is executed. Please give me a solution to this.

Thank you.

Comment: how you have changed port?